# find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\int_{0}^{1/n} x^{x+1} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)$$=$$n^2\int_{0}^{1/n} x^{x+1} dx$$ 
Help me to find out the limit of the function. I try to put $1/n=z$, then the function becomes $$\lim_{z\to 0}f(x)$$=$$1/z^2\int_{0}^{z} x^{x+1} dx$$
 Now I want to use L'hospital rule, but how do I show that the numerator becomes zero after applying L'hospital rule? If I am in a wrong way then help to do it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use L'Hospital's Rule to arrive at

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{\int_0^z x^{x+1}\,dx}{z^2}&=\lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{ z^{z+1}}{2z}\\\\&=\lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac12 z^z\\\\&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

Comment: fast as the flash (+1)

Comment: @tired Hello my friend!  Hope you're well.  Thank you!!

Comment: Note that the full limit doesn't exist. We need $z\to 0^+.$

Comment: but how does the limit of $z^z$ as z tends to $0$ become 1? Because $lnz$ tends to negative ${\infity}$ as $z$ tends to 0 and $1/z$ tends to positive ${\infity}$. Am i right about this? If not then help to find its limit.

Comment: @SubhankarSaha We need $z\to 0^+$.  I had presumed that $z>0$.  I've edited.

Comment: @zhw. Yes, of course.  I had tacitly assumed $z>0$. I've edited.

Comment: yah now I get it. @Dr.MV

Answer (score 0):

You think correct since $\int _{ 0 }^{ 0 }{ { x }^{ x+1 }dx } =0$ by applying  L'hospit's rule we get

$$\lim _{ z\to 0 } f(x)=\lim _{ z\to 0 } \frac { \int _{ 0 }^{ z } x^{ x+1 }dx }{ { z }^{ 2 } } =\lim _{ z\to 0 } \frac { { z }^{ z+1 } }{ 2z } =\lim _{ z\to 0 } \frac { { z }^{ z } }{ 2 } =\lim _{ z\to 0 } \frac { { e }^{ z\ln { z }  } }{ 2 } =\lim _{ z\to 0 } \frac { { e }^{ \frac { \frac { 1 }{ z }  }{ -\frac { 1 }{ { z }^{ 2 } }  }  } }{ 2 } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } $$